# How can I make getopts ignore unspecified flags (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a script to which I pass a number of flags. Only some of those flags are used in this script and I want to loop over them using "while getopts". However, it seems this loop only works when all flags are specified. However, some of the flags are not for this script but are passed to another script and so I want to ignore them here.

```sh
while getopts ":W:" flag ; do
   case "${flag}" in 
       "W")
           _TASK=${OPTARG}
           ;;
   esac
done

if [ "${_TASK}" == "OK" ] ; then
   ./other_script.sh "$@"
fi
```

This code only works when I run it like this:

```
myscript.sh -W OK -f otherflag1 -g otherflag2 etc...
```

but not if I run:

`myscript.sh -f otherflag -W OK`

because now, it will not find the "-W" flag in the loop. So, passing the flags is now order-dependent which I find rather ugly. 
(Also, related to this: how can I strip "-W OK" from "$@" ?)

Comment: If you think it's ugly you should see how clang handles arguments meant to be passed to other programs :D

Comment: You are only looking for one flag starting with `-W` when you define `":W:"`, other flags are not parsed

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of do this, but it's a bit ugly and has several caveats:

- You need to know how to parse the flags you'll be passing on. For instance, if the `-f` flag takes an argument, then `-fWOK` needs to be passed on as is (or as `-f WOK`), but if not, then `-fWOK` is short for `-f -W OK`, and you need to apply and remove the `-W OK` part and only pass on `-f`.
- This means the flags to the other program must be in `getopts`-compatible format. That means probably no long options (like `--exclude=foo`) (well, mostly), and nothing weird like gnu `sed`'s `-i` flag (which takes an argument, but it *must* be directly attached, so `sed -i.bak` works, but `sed -i .bak` doesn't).
- This also means that flags must precede positional parameters. Or at least, the ones that apply to your script. For example `ls -l somefile.txt` is ok, but not `ls somefile.txt -l`.

With those caveats, here's a way to do it with `getopts`. In this example, `-W` is an flag to your script and takes an argument; `-a`, `-b`, `-c`, and `-d` are flags to the other program that *don't* take arguments; and `-e`, `-f`, and `-g` are flags to the other program that *do* take arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

pass_on=()    # We'll accumulate flags to pass on here
while getopts ":W:abcde:f:g:" flag ; do
        case "${flag}" in
            W )
                echo "got -W '$OPTARG' option" >&2
                _TASK=${OPTARG} ;;

            a|b|c|d )    # pass-on flags that DON'T take arguments
                pass_on+=("-${flag}") ;;

            e|f|g )    # pass-on flags that DO take arguments
                pass_on+=("-${flag}${OPTARG}") ;;

        \? )
            echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1 ;;

        : )
            echo "Missing argument to option -${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1 ;;
        esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))    # Remove the flags we've processed from the arg list

echo "Passed-on flags and arguments:"
printf " '%s'\n" "${pass_on[@]}" "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a rather simple workaround that worked perfectly well in my case (see [functions](https://git.jfischer.org:444/xeruf/dotfiles/src/commit/3ba0316e7d8899be50640fad33228409b6ed875e/.config/shell/functions#L73), which calls [b](https://git.jfischer.org:444/xeruf/dotfiles/src/commit/3ba0316e7d8899be50640fad33228409b6ed875e/.local/bin/scripts/b)):

Add a `--` before providing the foreign flags, thus `getopts` will see them as extra arguments and hand them off untouched.

It will not eliminate the order dependence though, unfortunately.